# Compounding returns in a loop and char to date

Tags: r

I try to calculate "compounding" returns.

return1 are the returns in %.
I try to find out what the maximum return is.

For this I start with 100 and multiply 100 with (0.01 + 1) and this result should be multplied by 0.0099099 +1 and so on.

How can I improve my code below to achieve this within a loop?

Note: The vector return1 is just an example, there will be stored a more values than just this 5 ones.

Second question, does anyone know why the second code doesn't work? I get NA's and dates in betterDates...

Thank you for your help!

return1 = c(0.01000000,  0.00990099, -0.01960784,  0.20000000, -0.44166667)

```
a <- c(100,101,102,100,120,67)
return1 <- diff(a)/a[-length(a)]


zz <- c()
count <- 0
for (i in return1){
  count <- count + 1
  zz[count] <- 100*(i+1)
}

#2.
da <- c("March 30 2020", "February 13 2019", "March 2 2016","September 21 2015","September 21 2015","October 25 2013")
betterDates <- as.Date(da, format = "%B %d %Y")

> betterDates
[1] NA           NA           NA           "2015-09-21" "2015-09-21" NA
```

Comment: Assuming there's a typo in your definition of `da` (commas missinge between elements of the vector), I am unable to reproduce your problem with `betterDates`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have put the commas in. Now you should be able to reproduce it. :)

Comment: No, as I wrote, after insering the commas, I am _unable_ to reproduce.

Comment: Hmm, when I run it, it works,  but of course the same problem occurs as before.

Comment: For the second problem, probably you need to set the locale to English: ```Sys.setlocale(category = 'LC_TIME', locale = "en_US.UTF-8")```

Comment: Thank you José, it worked! :D Do you have some suggestions to my first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zz in the question equals the following so a loop and the intermediate variables are not really needed.

```
zz2 <- 100 * a[-1] / a[-length(a)]

# check
all.equal(zz, zz2)
## [1] TRUE
```

or equivalently zz equals

```
zz2a <- 100 * (return1 + 1)
all.equal(zz, zz2a)
## [1] TRUE
```

If you want to do it with a loop anyways then

1. Normally `i` is used as an integer index. Using that name to represent components of return1 is confusing.
2. The intermediate variables are not actually needed.  We can make do with the result, zz3, and n for the length of a. Although it would be possible to replace n with length(a) everywhere because n is used multiple times it is probably clearer to name it.
3. R works better when results are pre-allocated rather than than incrementally expanded.
4. n should be at least 2 so consider checking for that.  If n is not greater than 1 it returns NA.

This will compute it using a loop.

```
n <- length(a)
if (n > 1) {
  zz3 <- numeric(n-1)
  if (n > 1) for(i in seq_len(n-1)) zz3[i] <- 100 * a[i+1] / a[i]
} else zz3 <- NA

# check
all.equal(zz, zz3)
## [1] TRUE
```

Alternately `zz3[i] <- 100 * (return1[i] + 1)` could be used in the body of the loop.

The second part of the question has already been answered in the comments.

Comment: It's unfortunately not correct, with your code i get : 101.00000 100.99010  98.03922 120.00000  55.83333. But I need: 101,102,100,120,67. Because the returns are: (0.01000000, 0.00990099, -0.01960784, 0.20000000, -0.44166667) as I already mentioned. When I start let's say with 100 USD I would get 100*(1+0.01) = 101, then 101*(1+0.00990099) = rounded(102), then 102*(1+(-0.01960785) = 99.999 rounded (100) and so on.

Comment: That is exactly what zz in the answer gives.  The question was asking "how to improve the code", not how to produce a different result.

Comment: If you are looking for an answer of `c(101, 102, 100, 120,  67)` then 
`round(Reduce(function(x, y) x*(y + 1), return1, init = 100, acc = TRUE)[-1])` or maybe you want `Reduce(function(x, y) round(x * (y + 1)), return1, init = 100, acc = TRUE)[-1]` -- I can't be sure from your comment.